# Startup Script Centos only Launches One PHP Script

Tags: php, upstart

```
start on run level [2345]
stop on run level [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 15 5

script
   exec su - datafeeder - c 'php /home/datafeeder/ftp.php' >> /home/datafeeder/ftp.log
   exec su - datafeeder - c 'php /home/datafeeder/parse.php' >> /home/datafeeder/parse.log
   sleep 1m

end script
```

The above code only runs the first php script and then ends up respawning and eventually the entire script stops due to too many respawns. What I cannot figure out is the reason for the respawning. I can run the different scripts manually and they work fine but within this script the second one never gets called and the sleep command is never run as well.

Comment: exec is like exec in C, it **replaces the running shell script with that executable**. So your second exec will never be run because the call no longer exists.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake.... oh well, thanks for the reply.